# Fastest way to clear the child nodes of svg element without removing event.target

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

**Edit:**
If any event is hooked on the child element through jQuery, then use $.empty, otherwise memory leak will occur.

I am adding pinching support for my SVG widget. There is about 50 or more svg child nodes. I am using following code to draw the widget during touchmove or pointermove.

```
function pinchMoveHandler(event){
    var svg = this.widgetObject;
    event.target.id = "";
    event.target.setAttribute("opacity", 0);

    //do not remove event.target during touchmove or pointermove
    //If removed, event will be suspended
    svg.appendChild(event.target);
    while(svg.childNodes.length > 1)
         svg.removeChild(svg.firstChild);

    //Scaling and re-rendering operations will take place here
    this.drawWidget(event);
}
```

The problem is, svg removed slowly (40 milliseconds during continuous pointermove event in IE11) because pointer move triggered one after another even if I don't move my finger. What is the fastest way to clear an SVG element in JavaScript? jQuery solution is also acceptable too.

**Note:** In normal scenario, SVG removed in less than 10 milliseconds

Comment: Set them all to display:none perhaps?

Comment: @RobertLongson, I am talikng about pointer move event. In less than 1 second, svg will have 1000 child elements if I set display:none

Comment: @RobertLongson, appendChild will add element as last child element, even if it is already added. I am not sure about this but this is how it works in modern browsers

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild read the first two paragraphs.

Comment: yes, this is exactly what I meant in my previous comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118632/discussion-between-kira-and-robert-longson).

Answer (score 1):

**jQuery Solution;**

```
$("#mySVG").empty();
```

**jQuery Solution-2; (Prevent target)**

```
$(svg).children().not(':last').remove();
```

**jQuery Solution-3; (Prevent target)**

```
$(svg).find('*').not(':last').remove();
```

**jQuery Solution-4; (Re-append target)**

```
$(svg).empty().append(event.target);
```

**Suggested Solution;**

If you don't have any other operation to do, I suggest you  that; "make a clear copy" of SVG. I mean, create new (empty) SVG and replace old one with that.

Comment: if I use above code, event.target will be removed. Pointer move or touch move event will not trigger again.

Comment: Do you mean jQuery solution?

Comment: yes, it will remove all child nodes including event.target

Comment: If yes, still you can append event.target to inside of SVG. Also if you share your SVG template, we can try to give correct jQuery selector statement to ignore `event.target`.

Comment: Try this one; `$(svg).children().not(':last').remove();`and please share your performance test results.

Comment: I added more alternatives, can you test all of them (if you have time) and inform us about best result?

Comment: My JavaScript code is faster than jQuery. Also reappending not working.Here is a test fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/5p2m5phq/

Answer (score 0):

Since 2020 you can call `svgElement.replaceChildren()` to quickly empty out a node.